# issues with 1D heat equation

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics

This code simulates the temperature evolution in the soil over a period of 48 hours using the heat equation, here is a summary :

It imports the necessary libraries: numpy for numerical computations and matplotlib for plotting.

It defines the constants used in the simulation: D (thermal diffusivity of the soil), depth (depth of the soil), time_start (start time in seconds), time_end (end time in seconds), and delta_t (time step size in seconds).

It performs discretization by defining delta_x (reduced spatial step size) and calculates the number of spatial and temporal steps based on the given depth and time parameters.

It initializes an array called temperature with zeros, which will store the temperature values at different depths and times.

It sets the initial conditions for the temperature array, where all depths have an initial temperature of 22.5 degrees Celsius.

It sets the boundary condition at the surface (x = 0) based on the given parameters: To (average external temperature) and Tm (amplitude of external temperature variation). The boundary condition varies with time using a cosine function.

It interpolates the provided real temperature values to match the time steps in the simulation. This allows a comparison between the simulated and real temperatures.

It calculates the phase shift, dephasage, based on the depth using the formula provided.

It determines the depth index corresponding to 4 cm depth.

It solves the heat equation using a nested loop. The outer loop iterates over time steps, and the inner loop iterates over spatial steps. The temperature values at each depth and time are updated using the heat equation formula.

It calculates the temperature at a depth of 4 cm (temperature_4cm) by adding the boundary condition to the temperature values at that depth.

It plots the evolution of the real temperature values and the simulated temperature at 4 cm depth over time using matplotlib.

Overall, this code simulates the temperature variation in the soil over time and compares it with the provided real temperature values.

```
real_temperature_values= [22.50, 22.50, 22.30, 22.30, 22.20, 22.20, 22.10, 22.10, 22.10, 22.10, 22.10, 22.10, 22.10, 22.20, 22.30, 22.40,
22.50, 22.60, 22.70, 23.00, 23.20, 23.40, 23.70, 23.90, 24.00, 24.20, 24.40, 24.60, 24.70, 24.90, 25.10, 25.30,
25.60, 26.10, 26.60, 27.30, 28.20, 29.10, 30.00, 30.70, 31.50, 32.40, 33.20, 34.00, 34.90, 35.70, 36.50, 37.20,
37.90, 38.40, 38.90, 39.20, 39.20, 38.90, 38.50, 37.90, 37.40, 36.90, 36.40, 35.90, 35.40, 35.00, 34.50, 34.10,
33.80, 33.40, 33.10, 32.80, 32.50, 32.20, 32.00, 31.80, 31.50, 31.30, 31.00, 30.80, 30.60, 30.40, 30.10, 29.90,
29.70, 29.40, 29.20, 29.00, 28.80, 28.60, 28.40, 28.20, 28.10, 27.90, 27.70, 27.50, 27.40, 27.20, 27.10, 27.00,
26.80, 26.70, 26.60, 26.50, 26.40, 26.30, 26.20, 26.10, 26.00, 25.80, 25.80, 25.60, 25.60, 25.50, 25.40, 25.30,
25.20, 25.10, 25.00, 25.00, 24.90, 24.80, 24.70, 24.60, 24.60, 24.50, 24.50, 24.40, 24.40, 24.40, 24.30, 24.20,
24.20, 24.20, 24.20, 24.10, 24.00, 24.00, 24.00, 24.00, 23.90, 23.90, 23.80, 23.80, 23.80, 23.70, 23.60, 23.60,
23.60, 23.50, 23.50, 23.40, 23.40, 23.40, 23.40, 23.40, 23.40, 23.50, 23.50, 23.50, 23.50, 23.60, 23.60, 23.80,
23.90, 24.00, 24.20, 24.40, 24.60, 24.80, 25.00, 25.20, 25.50, 25.60, 25.80, 26.00, 26.20, 26.40, 26.60, 26.90,
27.10, 27.40, 27.90, 28.50, 29.10, 30.00, 30.60, 31.20, 31.90, 32.60, 33.40, 34.00, 34.60, 35.00, 35.20, 35.10,
35.00, 34.60, 34.30, 34.00, 34.10, 34.50, 35.10, 35.70, 36.20, 36.50, 36.90, 37.10, 37.40, 37.50, 37.50, 37.50,
37.30, 37.20, 37.10, 36.90, 36.50, 36.10, 35.70, 35.20, 34.90, 34.60, 34.40, 34.00, 33.60, 33.30, 32.90, 32.50,
32.20, 31.80, 31.50, 31.10, 30.80, 30.50, 30.10, 29.90, 29.70, 29.40, 29.20, 29.00, 28.80, 28.60, 28.40, 28.20,
28.10, 27.90, 27.70, 27.50, 27.40, 27.20, 27.00, 26.80, 26.70, 26.50, 26.40, 26.20, 26.10, 26.00, 25.80, 25.80,
25.60, 25.50, 25.40, 25.30, 25.20, 25.10, 25.00, 25.00, 24.90, 24.80, 24.70, 24.60, 24.50, 24.40, 24.40, 24.40,
24.20, 24.20, 24.20, 24.10, 24.00, 24.00, 24.00, 24.00, 23.90, 23.90, 23.80, 23.80, 23.70, 23.60, 23.60, 23.60]
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Constants
D = 4e-7  # Thermal diffusivity of the soil (units: m^2/s)
depth = 0.04  # Depth in m
time_start = 6 * 60 * 60 + 50 * 60  # Start time in seconds (6:50 am)
time_end = time_start + 48 * 60 * 60  # End time in seconds (next day 6:50 am)
delta_t = 60  # Time step size in seconds

# Discretization
delta_x = 0.001  # Reduced spatial step size in m

# Calculate the number of spatial and temporal steps
num_x_steps = int(depth / delta_x) + 1
num_t_steps = int((time_end - time_start) / delta_t) + 1

# Initialize temperature array
temperature = np.zeros((num_x_steps, num_t_steps))

# Set the initial conditions
temperature[:, 0] = 22.5  # Initial temperature at all depths (units: Celsius)

# Set the boundary condition at x = 0 (surface)
To = 29.364  # Average external temperature
Tm = 57.9 - 19.9  # Amplitude of external temperature variation (units: Celsius)
w = 2 * np.pi / (24 * 60 * 60)  # Angular frequency of external temperature variation     (units: rad/s)
boundary_condition = To + Tm * np.cos(w * np.linspace(time_start, time_end, num_t_steps))

# Real temperature values
real_temperature_values = np.interp(
    np.linspace(time_start, time_end, num_t_steps),
    np.linspace(time_start, time_end, len(real_temperature_values)),
    real_temperature_values)

# Calculate the phase shift based on depth
dephasage = (1.38 * np.sqrt(D) * np.arange(num_x_steps)) / depth

# Calculate the depth index
depth_4cm_index = int(0.04 / delta_x)  # Index corresponding to the depth of 4 cm

# Solve the heat equation
for t in range(1, num_t_steps):
    temperature[0, t] = boundary_condition[t] * np.exp(-dephasage[0])  # Update the     boundary condition at x = 0 (surface)
    for x in range(1, num_x_steps - 1):
        temperature[x, t] = temperature[x, t - 1] + (D * delta_t / (delta_x ** 2)) * (
            temperature[x + 1, t - 1] - 2 * temperature[x, t - 1] + temperature[x - 1, t - 1])

# Calculate the temperature at 4 cm depth
temperature_4cm = temperature[depth_4cm_index, :] + boundary_condition

    # Plot the temperature evolution
time = np.linspace(time_start, time_end, num_t_steps)
plt.plot(time, real_temperature_values, 'b-', label='Real Temperature')
plt.plot(time, temperature_4cm, 'r-', label='Simulated Temperature at 4 cm depth')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Temperature (°C)')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Temperature Evolution')

plt.show()
```

there is an error message "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars temperature[x, t] = temperature[x, t - 1] + (D * delta_t / (delta_x ** 2)) * ("

Does anyone know how to fix the error message? If I change D to 10e-20 the code works but i would like to use D = 4e-7

While on the subjects, if anyone is good at physics I would mind some help to recreate with the heat equation the real temperature values

Comment: What error message? Why not set it up in a CFD package StarCD or Phoenics for example or Openfoam?

Comment: @SolarMike its "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  temperature[x, t] = temperature[x, t - 1] + (D * delta_t / (delta_x ** 2)) * ("

Comment: Why multiply by an open bracket at the end? also add important information clearly to your original question, don't leave it in the comments.

Comment: @SolarMike on my code there isnt an open bracket it's just the error message

Comment: @SolarMike A CFD package for the 1D heat equation is really taking a cannon to shoot a sparrow. The heat equation is really a simple exercise that anyone who had a semester of numerical analysis for PDEs should be able to solve from scratch with ease, and eaven easier with a few Python libraries. Alas, I give that as a programming exercise to students who did even have the numerical analysis yet, it is as simple as that. Learning how to do that in Openfoam can easily take more time and I use it regularly.

Comment: @SolarMike *"Why multiply by an open bracket at the end?"* The code continues on the next line, which is fine in Python as long as you are wthin open brackets

Comment: @slothrop then it should be shown as complete in the comment or better yet shoukd have been properly added to the original question when first posted.

Comment: @SolarMike the complete multi-line statement is in the source code that OP has posted. The truncation of that statement is done by numpy in the warning message - it's not something that OP has done artificially. I don't think we expect questioners to tamper with system-produced error messages to make them more informative.

Comment: @ElisaGodwin does it work better if you make the time step smaller?

Comment: The method is explicit so the time restriction will be quadratic (~h^2). The classical Crank-Nicolson semi-implicit time stepping works very well for the heat equation, although basic computations are doable also with an explicit method and a short-enough  time step.

Comment: @slothrop not really . Also, what i don't understand is that my code still manages to plot a graph even with the error message.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава yes i really want to use the explicit method

Comment: @ElisaGodwin it's a warning rather than an error per se: something seems to be overflowing, and you may end up with NaNs somewhere (but possibly not at the point where x=4cm, which is ultimately what you plot)

Comment: When using this explicit method to solve the 1D heat equation, for stability you must have `2*D*delta_t/(delta_x)**2< 1`. With your numbers, that value is 48. So, your solver is unstable leading to numerical issues, hence your error. When you use `D = 10e-20`, then `2*D*delta_t/(delta_x)**2 = 1.2e-11`, which is less than 1 and hence stable.

Comment: If you want this method to be stable, you can either adjust `delta_t` or `delta_x` (or both) such that the condition is satisfied. Keeping `delta_x` the same, we can solve for `delta_t` that satisfies the condition and find that `delta_t < 1.25`. It's best to go a little lower so try using `delta_t = 1` (or go down to `0.75` if you still have issues).